# How to solve "content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' " Runtime error in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I know that this question may be marked as a duplicate but before any mod does that I'd wish to point out that I've tried those solutions and they didn't work out for me. My problem.(most likely)
The fragment FirstPane fails to inflate. Here's the stacktrace.

BTW my code is open source. You can find it at https://github.com/Boggartfly/OpenAirplay

I hope you find my code reasonably good.
I'm trying to stream content to my Apple TV so that why the apps named like that. Plus when this is done I'll post it on Google Play!
Thanks a lot guys!

UPDATE:
So here's what I actually know of this bug.
Caused due to Android not finding the required ListView with id  android.R.id.list

All known bug fixes do not work as of now. (Maybe I'm placing the bug fix in the wrong XML layout file)
When fragment first pane is set as a ListFragment then compilation succeeds but a runtime exception is thrown and a Force Close Occurs.(Error inflating class Fragment Binary error in XML line 20). But when FirstPane extends a Fragment, setListAdapter(adapter); fails to compile.

Stack trace:-

```
    04-18 16:52:33.840: D/AndroidRuntime(11445): Shutting down VM
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): Process: code.laerstudios.openairplay,     PID: 11445
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{code.laerstudios.openairplay/code.laerstudios.openairplay.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at code.laerstudios.openairplay.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    ... 9 more
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    04-18 16:52:33.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The fragment firstpane fails to inflate. You can check out the source code at github. Plus i don't understand why this question has been downvoted.

Comment: please your code over here where you found this errors?

Comment: Its a runtime error actually...

Comment: heres the link https://github.com/Boggartfly/OpenAirplay/blob/master/src/code/laerstudios/openairplay/FirstPane.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the stacktrace to the bottommost nested exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

The layout you use with `ListFragment` (and `ListActivity`) must have a `ListView` with that id. You can set it in XML with

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: doesn't work i tried. Have you got a functional build? The source is at https://github.com/Boggartfly/OpenAirplay

Comment: If yes pls help me by submitting me a pull request on github! I'll happily accept it if its valid!

Comment: Consider posting the relevant code here and work with the Stack Overflow Q&A model. Expecting people to fork and fix the code for you is a lot to ask.

Comment: Sorry if I overstepped but the code itself is across different files.. So idk whether I should post it here. I'm just saying if you're interested see my repository.

Comment: This solved my issue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143943/content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list